# Angular 2 [(ngModel)] throws error when placed between <form></form>

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I have a component.html with a form with a code that looks like this:

```ts
<div *ngIf="client">
    //More divs
   <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #clientForm="ngForm">
      <div>
         <input class="form-control" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="client.name" required>
      </div>
    //End of more divs
   </form>
</div>
```

But I keep getting an error when the componente is rendering the html:

```ts
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object
```

It only happens if I place the **input tag** between the form. Where it should be. If I place the input tag above and prior to the **form tag** it renders just fine with the data. Why could this be happening?

Comment: In addition where is your closing </form> tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing your `name` attribute on the input control. Should be

```
<input class="form-control" name="clientName" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="client.name" required>
```

If you delete the name attribute and open up the console you'll see the error message as follows:

> If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must
>   be set or the form
>         control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tH6g58pD6gDgp9ekRb0T?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Its not about placing i assume you have  not defined object `client` since you are binding to `client.name`;
You must init to default value like

```
client = {};
```

In your component or real client object

PS. I would like to recommend you to stop using NGModel go with [FormGroup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html). After you start using it you will love them :) fast, easy and flexible

Comment: The object is defined, the *ngIf also works, not sure why the ngModel doesn't here.  I updated the code above to illustrate where the </form> tag is

Comment: What if you update [(ngModel)]="client.name" to [(ngModel)]="test"

Comment: I receive same results